# SwiftUI List starts off expanded. How do I get the is to start off collapsed?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

For some reason, this list is starting off expanded. How do I get it to start off collapsed?
Everything is working as I desire but for some reason the list doesn't want to start off in the collapse position every time the view is opened.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContactView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            contactSection(title: "HR Department", phone: "(123) 456 - 7890", fax: "(123) 456 - 7890")
            contactSection(title: "Customer Service Department", phone: "(123) 456 - 7890")
            contactSection(title: "Technical Support Department", phone: "(123) 456 - 7890", afterHours: "(123) 456 - 7890", email: "support@support.com")
            contactSection(title: "Product Sales Department", email: "sales@sales.com")
            contactSection(title: "Contact App Developer", email: "appdev@appdev.com")
            Text("Office hours at this company is from Monday through Friday from 9:00 AM - 5:00 PM Eastern Time")
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
        .navigationTitle("Contact Info")
    }
    private func contactSection(title: String, phone: String? = nil, fax: String? = nil, afterHours: String? = nil, email: String? = nil) -> some View {
        Section(header: Text(title)
            .font(.headline)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)) {
                if let phone = phone {
                    contactItem(label: "Phone:", value: phone)
                }
                if let fax = fax {
                    contactItem(label: "Fax:", value: fax)
                }
                if let afterHours = afterHours {
                    contactItem(label: "After Hours Support:", value: afterHours)
                }
                if let email = email {
                    contactItem(label: "Email:", value: email)
                }
            }
    }
    private func contactItem(label: String, value: String) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(label)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.leading)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qRrf.png)
            Spacer()
            Text(value)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                .padding(.trailing)
        }
    }
}
struct ContactView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactView()
    }
}
```

The .listStyle(.whatever) is not giving me the desired affect. Swift says by default, the list should be collapsed.

Comment: Are you looking for `DisclosureGroup` or `OutlineGroup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sidebar` list style doesn't seem to support this currently. All the sections are expanded by default.

You can try making your own disclosures with `DisclosureGroup`, and try recreating an appearance similar to the `.sidebar` style.

Here is my attempt:

```
private func contactSection(title: String, phone: String? = nil, fax: String? = nil, afterHours: String? = nil, email: String? = nil) -> some View {
    Section {
        DisclosureGroup {
            Group {
                if let phone = phone {
                    contactItem(label: "Phone:", value: phone)
                }
                if let fax = fax {
                    contactItem(label: "Fax:", value: fax)
                }
                if let afterHours = afterHours {
                    contactItem(label: "After Hours Support:", value: afterHours)
                }
                if let email = email {
                    contactItem(label: "Email:", value: email)
                }
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: -16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            .listRowSeparator(.automatic)
        } label: {
            Text(title)
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}
```

Each section of the list contains a `DisclosureGroup`, in which all the hidden rows are located. The `DisclosureGroup` itself has `.listRowBackground(Color.clear)` and `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` to make the disclosure label look more like a section header (but it actually isn't).

The hidden rows all have the reverse: `.listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))` and `.listRowSeparator(.automatic)`.

The hidden rows all have a negative leading inset, to remove the inset added by the `DisclosureGroup`, which I think is a bit too much inset.

Output looks like this:

[image]

Caveats:

The sections are rather far apart. The spacing can be removed by [`.listSectionSpacing(0)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/listsectionspacing(_:)-a2sn) if you are on iOS 17.

The top of the hidden rows also have their top flat, rather than rounded, because the disclosure label is technically the first row of the section.

An alternative to consider is to just get rid of the "section header" appearance (remove all the `listRowBackground` and `listRowSeparator`), and put everything in a single section (i.e. remove the `Section { ... }`, and let `contactSection` directly returns the `DisclosureGroup`).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The updated code you've provided has given me the desired layout and action I was looking for. Thank you so much for taking your time to look into this and explaining it to me. I've spent the last couple days trying to figure that out. I tried to upvote your answer but my account is still new to StackO and I don't have enough "reputation".

Answer (score 0):

The list is starting out open because of your `contactSection()` function code. You are checking if phone, fax, afterHours, and email are filled. In your `List`, you wrote this code:

```
contactSection(title: "HR Department", phone: "(123) 456 - 7890", fax: "(123) 456 - 7890")
        contactSection(title: "Customer Service Department", phone: "(123) 456 - 7890")
        contactSection(title: "Technical Support Department", phone: "(123) 456 - 7890", afterHours: "(123) 456 - 7890", email: "support@support.com")
        contactSection(title: "Product Sales Department", email: "sales@sales.com")
        contactSection(title: "Contact App Developer", email: "appdev@appdev.com")
        Text("Office hours at this company is from Monday through Friday from 9:00 AM - 5:00 PM Eastern Time")
```

You filled in the parameters for the function, so it is showing them. If you do not want these to be displayed at first, you can leave the `contactSection()` parameters blank in your `List`.

**Edit**: I suggest using `OutlineGroup` or `DisclosureGroup` for this purpose.

Documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup

Comment: I'm sorry, Im not that experienced in swift. Im not sure what you mean by leaving the parameters blank. If I do that, then those item spaces show up empty. (side note: Ive tried using chatGPT and its come up with other solutions but the end up destroying the current view. I added a photo to the post to show what I want it to look like but it isn't showing up.

Comment: @jay The if lets that you use should mean that the item spaces will not exist at all. There are built-in approaches in SwiftUI for the feature you requested. I have edited my answer to add in the documentation.